# glib how address to index g_ptr_array

Tags: c, glib, gnome, dynamic-arrays

I have 3 structures and I use **GNOME glib** library to **have dynamic** **array.**

```
typedef struct Neuron
{
    //number of inputs into neuron
    int NumInputs; 

    //growing array of weights for each input
    GArray* ArrWeight;

}neuron;

typedef struct NeuronLayer
{
    //number of neurons in layer
    int NumNeurons;
    //growing array of neurons 
    GPtrArray* ArrNeurons;
}layer;

typedef struct Net
{
    int numInputs;
    int numOutputs;
    int numHiddenLayers;
    int NeuronsPerHiddenLayer;
    //each layer of neurons 
    GPtrArray* ArrLayers;
}net;
```

I want write cycle like that

```
for (k = 0; k < Net->ArrLayers->pdata[i].ArrNeuron->pdata[j].NumInputs; k++)
```

But I dont know how address to array. Compiler (clang say) :

> member reference base type 'gpointer' (aka 'void *') is not
>         a structure or union.
>
> structure of Gptrarray:

```
 struct GPtrArray 
 {   
    gpointer *pdata;   
    guint    len; 
 };
```

I think i should write something like that

```
Net->ArrLayers->pdata[i*sizeof(layer)].ArrNeurons->pdata[j*sizeof(neuron)].NumInputs
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gpointer` is a generic pointer. You are using it to store a pointer of a specific type. So to access its elements you must use a type cast.

I will first try to break your statement down. It currently looks like this:

```
Net->ArrLayers->pdata[i].ArrNeuron->pdata[j].NumInputs
```

I assume `Net` is a variable of type `net *`.

`Net->ArrLayers` is of type `GPtrArray *`.

`Net->ArrLayers->pdata` is of type `gpointer *`, i.e. `void **`, a pointer to a pointer.

`Net->ArrLayers->pdata[i]` is thus of type `gpointer`, i.e. `void *`, a pointer.

Now you want to access its element. Judging from your context, you want to interpret this pointer as a pointer to `layer`. However, the compiler doesn't know that. You need to tell the compiler.

So you should add a cast, `(layer *)Net->ArrLayers->pdata[i]`.

Now since this is of type `layer *` and not `layer`, you still need `->` instead of `.` to access its element, so it should now become:

```
((layer *)Net->ArrLayers->pdata[i])->ArrNeuron
```

Now you need to access `pdata` again. This is the same as the above, so I'll skip the explanation and show you the correct method:

```
((neuron *)((layer *)Net->ArrLayers->pdata[i])->ArrNeuron->pdata[j])->NumInputs
```

As you can see this is very messy. It would be better to split this into several statements to enhance readability, and by doing so you may even skip the casts:

```
int current_num_inputs(net * Net, size_t i, size_t j) {
    layer *current_layer = Net->ArrLayers->pdata[i];
    neuron *current_neuron = current_layer->ArrNeuron->pdata[j];
    return current_neuron->NumInputs;
}
```

Then in your `for` loop:

```
for(k = 0; k < current_num_inputs(Net, i, j); k++) { // ...
```